# Create Fully_connected layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to create a separate full connection layer to handle the results of a convolution operation， My code is:

```
def logit(inputs, is_training=True, dropout_keep_prob=0.8, bottleneck_layer_size=128, reuse=None, scope='logit_alexnet_rt'):
    #end_points_l = {}
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'logit_alexnet_rt', [inputs], reuse=reuse):
      with slim.arg_scope([slim.batch_norm, slim.dropout], is_training=is_training):
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d, slim.max_pool2d, slim.avg_pool2d], stride=1, padding='SAME'): 
          net = inputs
          #end_points_l['PrePool'] = net
          net = slim.avg_pool2d(net, net.get_shape()[1:3], padding='VALID', scope='avg_pool2d')
          net = slim.flatten(net)
          net = slim.dropout(net, dropout_keep_prob, is_training=True, scope='dropout')
          #end_points_l['PreLogitsFlatten'] = net
          net = slim.fully_connected(net, 128, activation_fn=None, scope='bottleneck', reuse=None)
    return net#end_points_l
```

but it have some problems:`ValueError: Variable triplet_loss/logit_alexnet_rt/bottleneck/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`

Comment: Te error message is suggesting the change you should make to your code. You are defining `reuse=None` and it tells you it is not allowed, to change it to true or auto. My first python related contribution!

Comment: What Can I do?Change resue=None to True or False

Comment: If I read the error message right `[inputs], reuse=true)`. Do note I am in no way a python expert.